# WebView control type in Forms in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

I used to embed images and even websites in feature's form in QGIS 2 using Control Type WebView in field properties.

I don't seem to find the WebView Control Type in QGIS 3 anymore.

So, how can I display an Image in QGIS forms?

(The URL is stored in a field imageLink for each feature).

Comment: This QGIS 3 changelog link might help you: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/#feature-migrate-photo-webview-and-filename-widgets-to-attachment

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks! that worked! Can you write an answer so that I can accept it and help others in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes from QGIS 2.x to QGIS 3.0 are very well described in [Changelog for QGIS 3.0](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/#).

How to migrate Photo, WebView and FileName widgets to Attachment is illustrated with screen shot at https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/#feature-migrate-photo-webview-and-filename-widgets-to-attachment